# How to let users tag their friends in a Facebook status update posted from a tab on a Facebook page?

Tags: php, javascript, facebook, facebook-graph-api

Basically I am looking for a way to facilitate the tagging of friends in a pre-populated status update. On the tab users will fill out a couple details, including the friends they would like to tag, then we would like to pre-populate a status update, then prompt them if they would like to post it to their updates with the user tags in place. Any direction on this sort of thing would be greatly appreciated.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

The Facebook API doesn't currently support tagging in Status Updates. That functionality is limited to the site itself.

Comment: Is this still accurate? No tagging functionality exposed through the API?

Comment: Yep, still no tagging allowed.

Comment: Is this still accurate?