# Tagging friends in status updates from Facebook API

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

I recently came across [this blog post](http://www.insidefacebook.com/2009/09/14/developer-tip-how-to-tag-friends-in-status-updates-from-your-app-undocumented/) that said that it's possible to tag someone in a status update from a Facebook app (= from the API):

However, it doesn't seem to work for me.

It tried it in three different ways:

```
$post = $facebook->api('/me/feed', 'post', array(
    'access_token' => $session['access_token'],
    'message' => 'Hello @[562372646:Lionel Cordier], how are you?'
));
```

or

```
$access_token = $session['access_token'];
$message = 'Hello @[562372646:Lionel Cordier], how are you?';
$curl_post = 'access_token='.$access_token.'&message='.$message;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

or

```
$access_token = $session['access_token'];
$message = 'Hello @[562372646:Lionel Cordier], how are you?';
$curl_post = 'access_token='.$access_token.'&status='.$message;
$ch = curl_init();
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_URL, 'https://api.facebook.com/method/users.setStatus');
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_HEADER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_RETURNTRANSFER, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POST, 1);
curl_setopt($ch, CURLOPT_POSTFIELDS, $curl_post);
$data = curl_exec($ch);
curl_close($ch);
```

But nothing works. The result I have is "*Hello @[562372646:Lionel Cordier], how are you?*" on my wall.

But if I type "*Hello @[562372646:Lionel Cordier], how are you?*" directly in Facebook, it works correctly.

**What am I doing wrong?**

Comment: Here's some proof that it is possible somehow: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5Gh1_qw9A4

Comment: It is possible for photos, check my answer below,

Answer (score 7, accepted):

I was struggling with this problem last week and found the following bug report, which suggests (given the current ASSIGNED status) that it cannot be done yet:(

http://developers.facebook.com/bugs/395975667115722/

Comment: Indeed, seems impossible for now. Thank you!

Comment: Bug report says it's impossible, but https://apps.facebook.com/profile_ranking is breaking the laws of physics somehow

Comment: there is an undocumented fkey,fvalue: for tagging it was hidden on purpose, to keep users from spam tagging and flooding with notifications.  Unfortunately this may never be a tool for us.

Answer (score 6):

Yes it is possible in this format: @[{user_id}:1:{name}]

Try this tutorial: http://digitizor.com/2011/01/24/tag-user-facebook-graph/

Answer (score 6):

https://apps.facebook.com/profile_ranking is uploading a picture and you can tag people in pictures not in status messages.

To Tag people in picture

curl -F 'access_token=xxxxxx' -F 'url=https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png' 
-F 'message=@[100000891609024:Silient Killerz]'
https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos

In **Graph Api Explorer**
Make the call post, set url to https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos,
Add field with key message and value @[100000891609024:Silient Killerz] (replace it with your friend id and name)
Add another field with key url and value https://appharbor.com/assets/images/stackoverflow-logo.png
click submit

Comment: For https://graph.facebook.com/me/feed they are removing tags from message where as for https://graph.facebook.com/me/photos they still allow tags :)

Comment: @mtariq how do you know this?

Answer (score 5):

below code worked for me , try if you don't want to show place in post then use the same code i mentioned **$params['place']='155021662189';**  that code won't show the place in Post

```
             $params=array();       

             $params['message'] = "Hi Friends ";
             $params['tags']='12345678903,1234567654'; //comma separated friends ID's
             $params['place']='155021662189'; 

             $params['name'] = "Some namee";
             $params['link'] = "http://blaha.com";
             $params['description'] = "blah blah blah blah";
             $params['picture'] = "image link"; 
             $params['caption'] = "Join ";


            $shared=$facebook->api("/".$user['id']."/feed", "post", $params);
                         or 
                    $shared=$facebook->api("/me/feed", "post", $params);
```

Comment: Why is it that exactly this place id (155021662189) won't show up as place in the post??

Comment: i have no idea about that.. there were many bugs with FB api 2 years back and not much support from FB..

Answer (score 2):

I have tried for hour but I think there needs to add new bug report. It was working year before as posted by Debjit.

## You should make bug report to facebook. (If doesn't exist).

Have updated on following posts:

1. [how to tag users in application post of a facebook application](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5803864/how-to-tag-users-in-application-post-of-a-facebook-application)
2. [Tagging people in a Facebook Post?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5507430/tagging-people-in-a-facebook-post)
3. [Tagging a user in a wall post/update using Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/3099183/tagging-a-user-in-a-wall-post-update-using-facebook-api/4776656#4776656)
4. [How to let users tag their friends in a Facebook status update posted from a tab on a Facebook page?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186795/how-to-let-users-tag-their-friends-in-a-facebook-status-update-posted-from-a-tab)

Comment: I am unable to load https://apps.facebook.com/profile_ranking url from my machine.

Comment: To clarify, I still haven't solved this issue. I am not the creator of that app. I'm wanting to know how that app is managing to do tagged posts despite the API officially not supporting that.

Comment: How you are able to see that app managing to do tagged posts? I am unable to load application page given by you. And you have commented worked just now. Is it your app supports sometimes or you have coded wrongly?

Comment: Here's me using that app: http://www.youtube.com/watch?v=q5Gh1_qw9A4 I'd like to know how to make such a timeline post through the Graph API.