# Facebook JS SDK - Tagging friends in Feed Dialogs?

Tags: javascript, facebook, dialog, fbml, feed

Can you tag people in posts made via JS SDK Feed Dialogs?  Particularly in the message section ("Facebook Dialogs are so easy!").

[Feed Dialogs](http://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/dialogs/feed/)

Example of Dialog:
https://i.stack.imgur.com/TiLFP.png

If not, what would be the best method of replicating this?  Would I need to request publish_stream permissions and use Graph API?  I was looking at [Tagging friends in status updates from Facebook API](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4327353/tagging-friends-in-status-updates-from-facebook-api) comments and it seems that it may be flaky?

Thanks all

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Its down in the Facebook bug tracker as a wishlist so has no real priority for them to fix :(

https://developers.facebook.com/bugs/253872611331478