# Tag friends in status with Graph API

Tags: iphone, facebook, facebook-graph-api, tags, friend

I have been searching around Google and this site to find answer on my question. I found different answers and therefore I will open this question in order to get an "up to date" answer.

I am trying to tag a friend in a comment using the Facebook Graph API. I have read that this should be possible using `@[USER_ID:USER_NAME]` but I cannot seem to get it working. When I do so this will be removed from the comment and nothing else will happen.

E.g `Hello! @[12345:John Doe]` will become `Hello!` when posted.

This is my code for testing:

```
NSString *postMe = [NSString stringWithFormat:@"%@ @[MY_USER_ID:Simon St\u00f8vring]", [message text]];
NSMutableDictionary *params = [NSMutableDictionary dictionaryWithObjectsAndKeys:postMe, @"message", nil];
[facebook requestWithGraphPath:request andParams:params andHttpMethod:@"POST" andDelegate:self];
```

It takes the value from a text view, adds a tag to myself and posts the comment using the Graph API.

So, can anyone tell me if it's possible to tag friends in comments and status updates using the Graph API?

Comment: Relevant: [How to let users tag their friends in a facebook status update](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186795/how-to-let-users-tag-their-friends-in-a-facebook-status-update-posted-from-a-tab/5292749#5292749)

Comment: see above ^ tagging posts is not exposed through API as of today.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

This is clearly not possible, as mentioned by @jBit.