# Post message referencing users

Tags: facebook, api, facebook-graph-api

As a facebook app I want to post a message that references a set of users (e.g. @John Doe, @Tom Cruise) so that the message will show up on their wall (and their friends can see).

How can I do this programmatically? Through what API calls?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

[As stated by aFacebook employee](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186795/how-to-let-users-tag-their-friends-in-a-facebook-status-update-posted-from-a-tab/5292749#5292749), tagging users in statuses is not available through the API.

Comment: what specifically? can you elaborate?

Comment: Good to know it's called "tagging"!

Comment: I'm pretty sure they will add it at some time.  You can tag users in photos via the API after all.