# Trying to tag friends in status update with php

Tags: php, facebook, facebook-graph-api

If you post a status update or share  a link on facebook there is an option to tag your friends as being 'with you'. It's not the same as tagging them with @ symbols.

I first get the friend list and then try to add a 'with' parameter. Using chrome web developer tools didn't give much info as to how facebook does this.

```
shuffle($friends);

        $with = array();

        for($i = 0; $i < 2; $i++)
        {
            if($i < count($friends))
                array_push($with, array("tag_uid" => $friends[$i]));
        }


        $fields = array('name'          => $status['title'],
                        'message'       => $status['message'],
                        'caption'       => $status['caption'],
                        'with' => json_encode($with)),
                        'description'   => $status['desc'],
                        'link'          => $url,
                        'picture'       => $status['img']);

        $result = HTTP_POST("https://graph.facebook.com/" . $account->id . "/feed?access_token=$access_token",  // full URL to query
```

Comment: A quick google search gives [this](http://digitizor.com/2011/01/24/tag-user-facebook-graph/). Did you try this?

Comment: Or maybe its not possible as per [this](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/4186795/how-to-let-users-tag-their-friends-in-a-facebook-status-update-posted-from-a-tab/5292749#5292749)